# Separated legend between two variables in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a dataframe which look like this :

[image]

From it, I want to make a plot which look like this :

[image]

I used ggplot and LibreOffice Draw to make the above plot. I wish to use ggplot only.

Here is a reproducible example :

```
library (dplyr)
n = 5

df = data.frame (    
    time = c(1 : n),
    prediction_model1 = rnorm (n) %>% sort,
    prediction_model2 = rnorm (n) %>% sort,
    observed_values = rnorm (n) %>% sort    
)

df_plot = df %>% 
    pivot_longer (cols = c (prediction_model1, prediction_model2), names_prefix = "prediction_", values_to = "happyness")

ggplot (df_plot) +

    geom_point (aes (x = time, y = happyness, color = name), size = 2) +
    geom_line (aes (x = time, y = happyness, color = name)) +

    geom_point (aes (x = time, y = observed_values), shape = 5, size = 4) +
    geom_line (aes (x = time, y = observed_values)) +

    labs (color = "") +

    theme (legend.position = "bottom")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map the `shape` and `linetype` aesthetics to a character value:

```r
ggplot(df_plot, aes(x = time, y = happyness)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = name), size = 2) +
  geom_line (aes(color = name)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = observed_values, shape = 'Observed values'), size = 3) +
  geom_line (aes(y = observed_values, linetype = 'Observed values')) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = NULL, values = 5) +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = NULL, values = 1) +
  labs(color = NULL) +
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(keyheight = unit(20, 'mm'))) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = '#f3faff', color = 'gray60'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a way to increase the space between the two blocks "model1  model 2" and "Observed values" ?

Comment: @armandfavrot sure, try `legend.margin = margin(10, 50, 10, 50)` to your `theme` call. Adjust the 50 values to whatever works best for you.

Answer (score 2):

One alternative is to pivot the observed along with the predicted values.

```r
pivot_longer(df, -time, names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)",
             names_to = c("predobs", "name"), values_to = "happyness") %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, happyness, group = interaction(predobs, name))) +
  geom_line(aes(color = name), data = ~ filter(., name != "values")) +
  geom_line(data = ~ filter(., name == "values")) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = predobs), data = ~ filter(., predobs == "observed")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(observed = 5)) +
  labs(color = NULL, shape = NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

With your current `pivot_longer`, you have two `observed_values` for each `time`, which is doubling the points on the observed line. It might not be visible, but it's not hard to come up with changes where this might cause problems (and certainly make troubleshooting ggplot-problems a bit more difficult). Granted, this problem can be mitigated by adding `data=~distinct(., time, observed_values)` in your "observed" geoms.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are looking for exactly, but something like:

```
ggplot (df_plot) +
    
    geom_point (aes (x = time, y = happyness, color = name), size = 2) +
    geom_line (aes (x = time, y = happyness, color = name)) +
    
    geom_point (aes (x = time, y = observed_values, shape = 'Observed values'), size = 4) +
    geom_line (aes (x = time, y = observed_values)) +
    
    scale_shape_manual(values = 5, name = NULL) +
    labs(color = NULL) +
    theme_classic() + 
    theme(legend.position = "bottom", panel.background = element_rect(color = 'black', fill = 'lightblue1'))
```

[image]